# Passing props to onClick from server to client component in Next13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a button component in the Next13 application that can accept a function as props that will be executed on the onClick event. Of course, it is declared as `'use client'`

Button.tsx

```
"use client";

type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: () => void;
};

const Button = ({ children, onClick }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      className="bg-secondary-color py-4 px-14 rounded text-white"
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

And here is my implemantion Page (Server Component)

```
<Button onClick={() => console.log("hello from parent")}>
  <Link href="/test">Navigate to test</Link>
</Button>
```

In my page I can see an error:

***Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
<... onClick={function} children=...>
^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.***

How can I resolve it? I know that I can add 'use client' on top of my page but is this good approach if this is simple landing page and this button is the only interactive element on page?

I also want this button component to be universal and perform functions depending on the implementation which is the essence of React.

How can I resolve that? What approach is best for this type of implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client Components enable you to add client-side interactivity to your application
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components

`onClick` event handlers are part of client-side interactivity. Hence can be added only in client component.

The reason is because the Node.js server that renders your server components, by creating a static version of your app, knows nothing about browser APIs like DOM.

To solve this error, you need to add `"use client"` on top of your file to make that server component a client component. All components without this line in Next.js 13 is a server component.

Or you can make your `onClick` handler from the server component to the `Button.tsx`. If that `onClick` handler requires any data from the parent, you can pass that data (rather than passing `onClick` handler itself).

Like:

```
<Button>
  <Link href="/test">Navigate to test</Link>
</Button>
```

`Button.tsx`

```
"use client";

type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: () => void;
};

const Button = ({ children }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      className="bg-secondary-color py-4 px-14 rounded text-white"
      onClick={() => console.log('hello from child')}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

---

On a side note, client components can be imported into server components, but not the other way around.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer. I know that I can add "use client" at the top of my page (server component) and my problem will be resolve.
But is this good approach to transform whole page into client component when there is only one interactive element as button? I want my button to be reusable as much as possible and I can achieve that by passing function to my void props. Do I really need to transform any page to client component if I want to use button?

Comment: `Button.tsx` will be a client component. But you can create your `app/*/layout.tsx` or `app/*/page.tsx` as server component (meaning no event handlers, dom/browser apis, various react hooks). So most of the page will be server rendered. The client components will be rendered on the client.

Comment: I totally understand that what you wrote. I just want to implement that button on page.tsx. And pass from `page.tsx` to `button.tsx` function like `onClick={() => console.log("hello world from console")}` as a props that button can recive. So there is not any other way than declaring a `page.tsx` as client component and rednder whole page on client side to avoid error `Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.`?

Comment: Is there a need for the `onClick` to be in the server component? You can have it in your client component `Button.tsx`, and then pass whatever data that `onClick` requires from parent. Does that clarify?

Comment: Ok so... I will resolve my problem in the other way. I will just use built in <Link /> component in my case. I fell into a vicious circle :')

But about your latest comment, I fully understand that I can pass any data from parent to my onClick props but not a function (unless parent will be client component aswell).

Thank you for your time and any clarification Robin!